# ExtJS4 LinkButton Component

Tags: javascript, html, extjs, components, extjs4

I'm trying to create my own LinkButton component in Ext JS 4. Nothing new, right?

My code looks like this:

```
Ext.define('LinkButton', {
    extend: 'Ext.Component',
    xtype: 'linkbutton',
    autoEl: 'a',
    renderTpl: '<a href=\"javascript:;\">{text}</a>',
    config: {
        text: '',
        handler: function () { }
    },
    initComponent: function () {
        var me = this;
        me.callParent(arguments);

        this.renderData = {
            text: this.getText()
        };

        var handler = me.getHandler();
        if (handler) {
            me.on('click', handler);
        }
    }
});
```

So far so good! My LinkButton does look like a hyperlink anad my text content is in there. Graceful.

However, I can't get my component to fire an event when I click on it!

This particular line `me.on('click', handler);` is **not** working! Even if I change it from *on* to *addListener* it has no effect.

So question is: How do I add DOM events to my component? Or, even better, how do I *access* my own component's DOM element? I haven't been able to do any of that!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my proposition, which is basing on source from `Button` component:

```
Ext.define('LinkButton', {
    extend: 'Ext.Component',
    xtype: 'linkbutton',
    autoEl: 'a',
    renderTpl: '<a href=\"javascript:;\" id="{id}-btnEl">{text}</a>',
    config: {
        text: '',
        handler: function () { }
    },
    initComponent: function () {
        var me = this;
        me.callParent(arguments);

        this.renderData = {
            text: this.getText()
        };
    },
    onRender: function(ct, position) {
        var me = this, 
            btn;

        me.addChildEls('btnEl');

        me.callParent(arguments);

        btn = me.btnEl;

        me.mon(btn, 'click', me.onClick, me);
    },
    onClick: function(e) {
        var me = this;
        if (me.preventDefault || (me.disabled && me.getHref()) && e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        if (e.button !== 0) {
            return;
        }
        if (!me.disabled) {
            me.fireHandler(e);
        }
    },
    fireHandler: function(e){
        var me = this,
            handler = me.handler;

        me.fireEvent('click', me, e);
        if (handler) {
            handler.call(me.scope || me, me, e);
        }
    }
});
```

Working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/lolo/AEwH4/1/

Comment: Today I learntt the audoEl config I initially used was causing a double A tag because of the A tag in the template. Just remove that and it'll be fine.

Answer (score 3):

Or you can do this

```
afterRender : function() {
    this.callParent(arguments);

    this.mon(this.el, {
        scope : this,
        delegate : 'a',
        click : this.handleClick
    });
},

handleClick : function(e, t) {
    e.stopEvent();

    var handler = this.getHandler();
    if (handler) {
        handler();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is almost verbatim what I have done in my application!  I wasn't famililar with the `delegate` property, and I don't see it in the documentation.  What does it do?

Comment: It accepts a DOM selector of an element to have the listener fire. So that click listener will only fire for elements matching the 'a' selector. If the <a> tag had a class for example <a class="test">link</a> the you could use 'a.test' for the selector.

Answer (score 0):

the right way is to use [Ext.view.View](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.view.View) for such tasks. There is custom html that allow you to do anything, and in same time all the functionality of Ext.Component is available.